# Xfreerdp launcher shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcuts

I think it's a silly question but this issue annoys a bit. 
This is not a problem to create the shortcut or place it on the taskbar. I can do it.

The issue is this:

- I created a custom .desktop file to start xfreerdp using a script with the appropriate parameters
- I placed this desktop file in the taskbar (see button 1 in the image)
- When I run the shortcut, xfreerdp opens fine, but it's "placed" in a different shortcut in the taskbar (see button 2 in the image)

So... my question is about to avoid this behavior: Can I create a shortcut that is not replaced by another one in the taskbar when the program runs?

[image: taskbar with two shortcuts]

The contents of the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Name=TS
Comment=Open TS
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/user/bin/rdp_xfreerdp.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/48/gnome-remote-desktop.svg
```

The contents of the script rdp_xfreerdp.sh:

```
xfreerdp /v:ts.domain.com \
  /d:WG \
  /u:user  \
  /p:$(zenity \
  --entry \
  --title="Domain Password" \
  --text="Enter your _password:" \
  --hide-text) \
  /size:1290x912 \
  /bpp:24 \
  /sound \
  +clipboard \
&
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding the same `VM_CLASS` property in both places:

1. `StartupWMClass=rdptoserver1` to the desktop file
2. `/wm-class:rdptoserver1` to the `xfreerdp` script

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly.